# RTC checkout using Ant

Tags: ant, rtc

Is there a way to checkout files from RTC using Ant scripts?. I have a scenario where i need to checkout the files from RTC and build an app using Ant.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to invoke scm command through `<exec>` ant task.

You can see some examples in "[Using the SCM Command Line Interface in builds](https://jazz.net/library/article/195)"

```
<property name="run" value="/path/to/run_and_filter.pl"/>
<property name="scm" value="/path/to/scm"/>

<target name="__scm-checkin">
        <!-- Do the initial commit -->
        <exec executable="${run}" failonerror="true" outputproperty="cs">
            <arg value="${scm} --non-interactive -a n -u y checkin ${roots}"/>
            <arg value="      \(([^)]+)\)"/>
        </exec>

        <!-- Deliver -->
        <exec executable="${scm}" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="--non-interactive"/>
            <arg value="deliver"/>
            <arg value="${cs}"/>
        </exec>
</target>
```

Make sure to use scm though, not lscm which starts a damon and can cause the ant task to hang: see "[Calling `lscm.bat` from a build script causes a hang](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/77400/calling-lscmbat-from-a-build-script-causes-a-hang)".

Answer (score 2):

RTC does not have a "check-out" operation, which is implicit. It only has a check-in operation. If you want to get code from a repository workspace you can load it using scm command, as described before, or creating a java standalone using Plain API.